# Accessing variables in a Node web application using Vite

Tags: npm, vite

I have a very simple application built using npm and Vite.

I'd like to specify an external server URL that the application relies on, but I want that URL to be different when I run locally (`npm start`) versus the built version (`npm run build`, which calls `vite build`).

What is the recommended way of doing this?

It seems like the normal way to do this is via `.env`, but there's nothing secret about these two URLs and I'd want to put the configuration in version control. I was hoping to declare something in `vite.config.js` or `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define environment variables in the script part of package.json like this:

```json
{
  "name": "my-vite-appp",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL='https://dev_server.com' vite"
    "build": "EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL='https://build_server.com' vite build",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

And then in your code access the EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL variable like this: `const url = process.env.EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL;`

(I'm not experience with Vite itself, so the way to access the variable might be a bit different)

---

See the comment from bosth below for some detail that I missed.

Comment: This is almost correct. Two corrections and I can mark this as answered. First, the environment variables *must* start with the `VITE_` prefix. Second, they are referenced by `import.meta.env.VITE_EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL` rather than by `process.env`.

Comment: It seems like you did some extra research and know some Vite-specific details now that I didn't know about (as I use Nuxt, not Vite directly). Good work! I'm not relaxed with updating my answer with something I didn't try, so could you please write your own answer? -- you get the credits.

Comment: I did do some extra work but you pushed me in the right direction so happy to give this the ✅ with the two small edits!